# Component variable inside subscribe function of a behavioural subject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a *login service component* which has a behavioral subject `_loginEmailId" and the method` updateLoginEmailId(email:string)` to update its value as following.

```
private _loginEmailId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("")
currentLoginEmailId = this._loginEmailId.asObservable()

private _isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
isLoggedIn$ = this._isLoggedIn.asObservable();

changeLoggedInStatus(state:boolean){
        this._isLoggedIn.next(state);
}

updateLoginEmailId(email:string){
        this._loginEmailId.next(email);
}

login(email:string, password:string){
        //returns observable
}
```

In *Login Component* I am subscribing to a `login` method from *Login service component* by passing a email ID and password captured from a reactive form. Inside this subscribe function, after receiving the response I am trying to update the `_loginEmailId` in the login service, by calling `updateLoginEmailId(email:string)` so that I can use it in another component. But I am not able to pass `this.loginEmail` to the `updateLoginEmailId(email:string)`.
When I log `this.loginEmail` inside `subscribe` it logs null, outside subscribe it logs the correct value.
I know, this is bacause of `this` not referring to the component.

I have seen `that=this` hack, that did not work either.

How can I solve this.

My *Login Component* looks like this

```
export class LoginComponent{

  loginEmail:string;
  loginPassword:string;
 
}

login(form: NgForm){
    this.loginService.login(this.loginEmail, this.loginPassword).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.loginService.changeLoggedInStatus(true); //This works
        this.loginService.updateLoginEmailId(this.loginEmail); // The function is getting invoked 
            but the value for this.loginEmail is null.
        this.router.navigate(['/home']); //This works 
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    form.resetForm();

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscription is asynchronous, meaning it happens after the form is reset. you should move resetting the form inside of the subscription callback.